# Knockout.js Tabindex in a foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am applying tabindex to multiple rows of textareas in a foreach list. There is a button at the end of each row. I need the tabbing sequence to go from left to right for each row proceeding to the next row, etc.

How can it make the preceeding rows start at a higher number than the proceeding rows? 
eg: I expect: 
row 1: tabindex 1,2,3
row 2: tabindex 4,5,6

but I am getting (2nd row starting 1 less than expected):
row 1: tabindex 1,2,3
row 2: tabindex 3,4,5

```
  <ul data-bind="foreach: myForEach">
    <li>
      <div class="span11">
        <textarea rows="3" data-bind="attr: {  tabindex: ($index() + 1) }"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="span11">
        <textarea rows="3" data-bind="attr: {  tabindex: ($index() + 2) }"></textarea>
      </div>

      <a data-bind="attr: {  tabindex: ($index() + 3) }">delete row</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should multiply the index by 3:

```
data-bind="attr: { tabindex: ($index() * 3 + [index]) }"
```

The complete code:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: myForEach">
    <li>
        <div class="span11">
            <textarea rows="3" data-bind="attr: { tabindex: ($index() * 3 + 1) }"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="span11">
            <textarea rows="3" data-bind="attr: { tabindex: ($index() * 3 + 2) }"></textarea>
        </div>
        <a data-bind="attr: { tabindex: ($index() * 3 + 3) }">delete row</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This amount of the controls.